# Bad injection of maven properties in spring application context

Tags: spring, maven, pom.xml, applicationcontext, maven-profiles

I am trying to set up an activeMQ broker and apply it the following policyEntry:

```
<policyEntry 
    queue="${broker.destination.queue.prefix}>"
    gcInactiveDestinations="${broker.destination.purge.inactives}" 
    inactiveTimoutBeforeGC="${broker.destination.inactive.max.time}">
</policyEntry>
```

The variables points to an jms.properties with next entries:

```
broker.destination.purge.inactives =    true
broker.destination.inactive.max.time =  ${maven.jms.broker.destination.inactive.max.time}
```

Because of I have diferent profiles, last property point to the following property in POM file:

```
<maven.jms.broker.destination.inactive.max.time>30000</maven.jms.broker.destination.inactive.max.time>
```

With this context, I am having a problem with the policy entry because:

- **gcInactiveDestinations**: the broker expects a long value but it is being interpreted as Integer (I have tried with 30000L and 30000l and not work).
- **inactiveTimeoutBeforeGC**: must be interpreted as boolean but it has been interpreted as string.

How can I manage this situation?

Thanks!

Comment: Anyone knows a solution? I have found nothing in web and I think must be a common situation in many projects...

Comment: Can you show some stacktraces from this error?